# PHPMailer is not sending mails

Tags: php, email, smtp

Guys I have read many answers on this question but the problem still persists. 
The PHPMailer is not sending emails giving the following error.

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Following is the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
//$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port =25;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "mail@mail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom("mail@mail.com","Contact Form");
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['user_mail'], $_POST['user_name']);
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress("mail@mail.com", "Contact Form");
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'] . " - Contact Form";
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML("Message from ". $_POST['user_name']." : <br/>".$_POST['message'] . "<br/> Contact Details : <br/> Email :" . $_POST['user_mail'] . "<br/> Contact Number : " . $_POST['user_number']);
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
//$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "<script>window.location.href='thankyou.html';</script>";
}
```

Comment: set this `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` to `2` and show us a more detailed error. But that error would mean it wasn't able to connect to your smtp server

Comment: The error suggests it cannot connect to the SMTP server.  Are you using a public SMTP server (like gmail)?  Are you sure you have the username and password (and port) correct?

Comment: @hungrykoala Should i Delete some data from that error for security risks, posting it here

Comment: change the SMTP port number To 465 OR 587 if it not working config your sendmail.php file in you server set 
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com, smtp_ssl=auto and also set 
auth_username and auth_password

Comment: @SONGSTER please do so. Also, this are the errors `Invalid address` and `Password command failed`

Comment: so should i change the password

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya the OP did not mention the use of GMAIL as an smtp server so suggesting it is unecessary as it won't also work unless he enables it on his GMAIL account.

Comment: no its not a gmail account

Comment: password and email are correct

Comment: @SONGSTER That depends on what your correct password is. Also, try to make the email adress valid.

Comment: how? can you elaborate a little and could this be a port error. And whats a correct password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171515/discussion-between-hungrykoala-and-songster).